# Binomial $(n=7,k=3,p=?) = \text{Geometric}(p=?)$ where Geometric function succeeds on 3rd trial, what is $p$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I'm trying to find $p$ s.t the Binomial function of it succeeds $3/7$ times and the Geometric function succeeds on the 3rd attempt. I tried equating the functions but it was a mess

$$7C3p^{3}(1-p)^{4}=(1-p)^{2}p => 7C3p^{2}(1-p)^2=1$$

Comment: You can plug this sort of thing into [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%287+choose+3%29*x%5E2%281-x%29%5E2%3D1).  As for solving this by hand, its not feasible to do.  You [could possibly do it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots) but almost noone in modern history actually does any such calculations for quartics by hand, and for quintics or higher such a generalized formula *cannot* exist.  Wolfram gives the solutions for $p$ in the appropriate range as either approximately $0.21545$ or $0.78455$.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this special quartic equation, take square roots on both sides:
$$\sqrt{35}p(1-p)=1$$
Now apply the quadratic formula to solve for $p$.